# In Elasticsearch how can I get field length using the painless script?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm trying to update a field if it's longer than the existing one in an index, but neither of these function seem to work to get the length of a field

```
ctx._source.description.length() < params.description.length()
ctx._source.description.size() < params.description.size()
ctx._source.description.length < params.description.length
```

I get the same error that the methods don't exist. Any idea how to achieve this?

Edit:

This is the error I'm getting:

```
array:1 [
  "update" => array:5 [
    "_index" => "products_a"
    "_type" => "_doc"
    "_id" => "XjouMXoBeY37PI1TSOQl"
    "status" => 400
    "error" => array:3 [
      "type" => "illegal_argument_exception"
      "reason" => "failed to execute script"
      "caused_by" => array:6 [
        "type" => "script_exception"
        "reason" => "runtime error"
        "script_stack" => array:2 [
          0 => """
            if (ctx._source.description.length()<params.description.length()) {\n
            \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
            """
          1 => "                           ^---- HERE"
        ]
        "script" => "add_new_seller_to_existing_doc"
        "lang" => "painless"
        "caused_by" => array:2 [
          "type" => "illegal_argument_exception"
          "reason" => "dynamic method [java.util.ArrayList, length/0] not found"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Edit 2:

Stored script

```
    $params = [
        'id' => 'add_new_seller_to_existing_doc',
        'body' => [
            'script' => [
                'lang' => 'painless',
                'source' =>
                    'if(params.containsKey(\'description\')){
                        if (!ctx._source.containsKey(\'description\')) {
                            ctx._source.description=params.description;
                        } else if (ctx._source.description.length()<params.description.length()) {
                            ctx._source.description=params.description;
                        }
                    }'
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Bulk update command:

```
    $bulk_obj['body'][] = ['update' => ['_id' => $id, '_index' => 'products']];

    $bulk_obj['body'][] = ['id' => 'add_new_seller_to_existing_doc', 'params' => ['description'=>'some_description']];
```

Comment: Can you give sample of docs, and expected result?

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: @Val I'm running 7.6.0

Comment: @DoNhuVy It's part of a rather large index which uses a script to update values, so it would be hard replicating it here. But I edited the initial post to include the full error I'm getting in case that helps

Comment: The `java.util.ArrayList` class has a `size()` method, can you try it and show the error you get? I think I know where it's coming from. Also can you show the update by query you're running, with the `params`map

Comment: @Val I have also tried size and it throws the same error, I have update the post with and _update_by_query command. But when I run it in Kibana it works just fine. This is just part of a script I have stored and use it to update documents by feeding it the params via a bulk update operation. And for some reason that's when it fails...

Comment: Something I don't get, you're talking about bulk update, but update by query cannot be used in bulk updates... Can you show **exactly** what you're doing please (help us help you)?

Comment: @Val I have updated the original post to show exactly what I'm doing

Comment: First, the second line in your bulk is not correct, `id` and `params` should be wrapped inside `script` as can be seen [in this example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update)

Comment: Second, can you explain if `description` in the source document is always a list or always a string?

Comment: @Val always a string. Here is the kibana equivalent for the update, which gives the same error: `POST _bulk
{ "update" : { "_id" : "UkFFMnoBeY37PI1TSJ3P", "_index" : "products"} }
{ "script" : { "id" : "add_new_seller_to_existing_doc", "params" : {"description" : "Randmon description"}}}`

Comment: @Val I think this may be it description is an array... and I was taking into account it's a string. yep, this is it!!

Comment: In the kibana equivalent `id` and `params` are wrapped in `script` which is not the case in your bulk statement

Comment: The error states that `description` seems to be an ArrayList not a String

Comment: @Val yep, I was not careful in reading the error, I simply thought I was using the wrong length function, while in fact I was applying it on an array rather than a string... At this point it seems it works, converted the string to array, because it was an array holding just 1 value

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `description` field is an ArrayList awhile you think it is a String.

Either you use `ArrayList.size()` or you convert the ArrayList to a String (if it contains only one string) and you can then use `String.length()`

Answer (score 0):

Below should work to get length of a field:

```
doc['description'].value.length()
```